# how to deal with read() timeout in Redis client?

Tags: redis

Assume that my client send a 'INCR' command to redis server, but the response packet is lost, so my client's read() will times out, but client is not able to tell if INCR operation has been performed by server.

what to do next? resending INCR or continuing next command? If client resends INCR, but in case redis had carried out INCR in server side before, this key will be increased two times, which is not what we want.

Answer (score 4):

This is not a problem specific to Redis: it also applies to any other data stores (including transactional ones). There is no solution to this problem: you can only hope to minimize the issue.

For instance, some people tend to put very aggressive values for their timeout thinking that Redis is supposed to be a soft real-time data store. Redis is fast, but you also need to consider the network, and the system itself. Network related problems may generate high latencies. If the system starts swapping, it will very seriously impact Redis response times.

I tend to think that putting a timeout under 2 secs is a nonsense on any Unix/Linux system, and if a network is involved, I am much more comfortable with 10 secs. People put very low values because they want to avoid their application to block: it is a mistake. Rather than setting very low timeouts and keep the application synchronous, they should design the application to be asynchronous and set sensible timeouts.

After a timeout, a client should never "continue" with the next command. It should close the connection, and try to open a new one. If a reply (or a query) has been lost, it is unlikely  that the client and the server can resynchronize. It is safer to close the connection.

Should you try to issue the INCR again after the reconnection? It is really up to you. But if a read timeout has just been triggered, there is a good chance the reconnection will time out as well. Redis being single-threaded, when it is slow for one connection, it is slow for all connections simultaneously.

Comment: How does one configure this timeout value? Where in the configuration is it?

Comment: You will not find it in the server configuration: it is set on client side. The way to set it depends on the client (language, implementation, etc ...)